# How fix icons in tab layout

Tags: android, xml, android-tablayout

I am trying to place icons to left of the text in tab layout. I have done it so far but alignment is problem. Can some of help me how to align them so that text should overflow. Here is how it looking 
[image]

I want to align icon and text to each other like this

[image]

How to fix this? Help

Here is the code and xml that i am using

tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:textColor="#fff" />
```

Here is java code

```
TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab, null);
        tabOne.setText("Dashboard");
        tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_action_action_account_balance, 0, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

        TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab, null);
        tabTwo.setText("Nearby");
        tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_action_action_account_balance, 0, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

        TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab, null);
        tabThree.setText("Explore");
        tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_action_action_account_balance, 0, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);
```

here is entire xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabMode="fixed"

            app:tabTextColor="#fff"></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tab"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/consumer_header"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following `layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="CENTER_VERTICAL|LEFT"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:textColor="#fff" />
```

In case if still text is not fitting in one line or it's too small you may have to play with `textSize`

Comment: it fixes the alignment problem but dashboard's text splits into 2 lines

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir reduce `textSize` make it `12sp` and try

Comment: this will decrease the text size bro :(

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir you do not have any option. Either you need to set small Names to tab or reduce the textSize

Comment: yeah i have to do this.